# Argument type 'FluentNHibernate.Mapping.IProperty' is not CLS-compliant

Tags: c#, .net, cls-compliant

Name is not compliant? Layout? What?

Do you have ideas what exactly could generate this message? Any ideas are welcome. I have bunch of such warning.

Actually, I am open to remove CLSCompliant(true), but I want to know root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not just as simple as the `Fluent.NHibernate` assembly not being `CLSCompliant`? The  `IProperty` type isn't compliant, therefore a method taking it as a parameter isn't compliant.

Comment: Yeh! This is the case! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You might have a member that uses the same name with different casing - e.g. iProperty. Or perhaps you have two arguments that differ only in casing.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a case in my situation.